# Prevent Jupyter from printing loaded matrices with the octave kernel

Tags: octave, jupyter

I'm using the Octave kernel in a Jupyter notebook. When I try to load a matrix from a file using the dlmread function, the whole data is printed. I tried assigning the result to a variable immediately, but no luck. This is troublesome because the matrix is quite large (~17*500) so it takes a while to print.

I just want to load my data without having all of it printed.

Comment: Without showing the code we just can guess: I guess you don't have a ; at the end of your dlmread call

Comment: Yes, that's it. I did not know about the need for a semi-colon. If you want to turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you don't have a `;` at the end of your dlmread command. See the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Simple-Examples.html#Simple-Examples):

> Ending a command with a semicolon tells Octave not to print the result of the command

See this example:

```
>> a = 4 + 5
a =  9
>> b = 5 + 6;
>>
```